# Canvas efficiency when drawing many rectangles

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, rect, jcanvas

I have a two-dimensional array of colors derived from each pixel coordinate in an image. A slider determines the size of the pixelated rectangles and the image is redrawn in a pixelated form. In nested loops, jCanvas is used to draw each 'pixel' as a rectangle. There's significant slow down between adjusting the slider and the new canvas draw. What can be done to increase the efficiency of drawing many canvas rectangles? I hope to use this concept on images that are larger that the current 250x250, but only if the redraw is much more efficient.

When the slider value changes, this function is called:

```
$("canvas").clearCanvas();

for(var x = 0; x < colorMatrix.length; x += size) {
    for(var y = 0; y < colorMatrix[0].length; y += size) {
        $("canvas").drawRect({
            fillStyle: '#' + colorMatrix[x][y],
            x: (x), y: (y),
            width: size,
            height: size,
            fromCenter: false
        });
    }
}
```

Cheers,
tL

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uXBN5/

Here's a demo, scaled down to a much smaller size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a huge speed up merely by caching the `$("canvas")` value:

```
var canvas = $("canvas");
canvas.clearCanvas();

for(var x = 0; x < colorMatrix.length; x += size) {
    for(var y = 0; y < colorMatrix[0].length; y += size) {
        canvas.drawRect({
            fillStyle: '#' + colorMatrix[x][y],
            x: (x), y: (y),
            width: size,
            height: size,
            fromCenter: false
        });
    }
}
```

But if you really want to improve performance, you should use the [draw method](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/drawManually/) and put your entire loop within that function so you can use the raw `canvas` drawing API which will let you draw things faster.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the tips! It's so much faster now.

Answer (score 1):

You could detach element from DOM too, should optimize performance:

http://jsfiddle.net/uXBN5/1/

```
function updatePixelatedImage(size) {
    var $tmp = $('<div/>').insertBefore('canvas'),
        $canvas = $('canvas').detach();
    $canvas.clearCanvas();

    for(var x = 0; x < colorMatrix.length; x += size) {
        for(var y = 0; y < colorMatrix[0].length; y += size) {
            $canvas.drawRect({
                fillStyle: '#' + colorMatrix[x][y],
                x: (x), y: (y),
                width: size,
                height: size,
                fromCenter: false
            });
        }
    } 

    $tmp.replaceWith($canvas);
}
```

Comment: Also a great idea. This, combined with Brandon's answer, will make the entire solution many times more efficient. Thank you!

Comment: @roasted Interesting... Why does detaching the canvas improve performance? Is it to force the browser to render all rectangles at once rather than one at a time? Surprising there isn't a better way to do this...